# How to use labeler transformation in informatica developer?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, data-quality

I am new to this IDQ tool. can anyone give me a step by step instructions with some screenshots to know how to use the labeler transformation using reference tables.

Any video links related to labeler transforamtion using reference tables are also appreciated

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: can you help me to understand labeler transformation @Maciejg

Comment: I'm sorry - I won't be able to help here :( I don't work with IDQ and I have just an idea of features and way it works, but no hands-on experience.